# Calling and Declaring a select box in PHP!

Tags: php, html, css, select

I want to be able to change the color of my websites background depending on which option the user chooses.

I have this code for my select box:

```
<select name="change_date" >
<option value="1" id="1">1</option>
<option value="2" id="2">2</option>
<option value="3" id="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Using PHP, how would i get it so that it simply changed to red for 1, green for 2 and pink for 3?

This is the code I have tried (unsuccessfully and complete guesswork):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['change_date'])=='1' )
   {
   echo "<body style='background-color:red;'></body>";
   }else{
   echo "failed";
   }
if(isset($_POST['change_date'])=='2' )
   {
   echo "<body style='background-color:green;'></body>";
   }else{
   echo "failed";
   }
if(isset($_POST['change_date'])=='3' )
   {
   echo "<body style='background-color:pink;'></body>";
   }else{
   echo "failed";
   }

?>
```

Any suggestions? methods? links?

**UPDATE:
I have tried all methods and none seem to work guys. It must be something I am doing wrong. 
What i want is when the user chooses and option ie 1,2 or 3 and clicks send, then the color will change. 
Hope this helps more. I forgot to add before that I want a send button to have to be clicked then all the clever stuff happens.
Thanks**

Comment: Your problem was the use of `isset()`. It only returns a boolean state, not the value. You can simplify that with a switch or a map like `array("1" => "red", "2" => ...)`

Comment: Is the select wrapped in a form with the method set to POST? obvious question but I have to ask...

Comment: just the code as you see it literally thats it.

Comment: did you try merely echoing the post data to ensure you are actually passing and receiving the data you are using for the control structure?

Comment: All I did, was create a select box, and attempt to call it miserably

Comment: Do you have `<form action="yourscript.php" method="POST">` in there? Try doing a `print_r($_POST)` to see what's getting passed into the script.

Comment: as I thought, you aren't even sending the form :( go with a javascript method and save the option in a cookie.

Comment: @Ryan I just made an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jackJoe/RvEnA/ you need to add the cookie creation via javascript (plenty of examples on the internet), also in my example I placed the class on a div and not the `<body>` you can change that also; then you can create a PHP to read (if it exists) the cookie and apply the Class to the body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (isset($_POST['change_date']))
{
    switch ($_POST['change_date'])
    {
        case 1: $color = 'red'; break;
        case 2: $color = 'green'; break;
        case 3: $color = 'pink'; break;
        default: die('failed');
    }
    echo "<body style='background-color:$color;'></body>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a switch:

```
$color = !empty($_POST['change_date'])?$_POST['change_date']:0;

switch ($color) {
    default:
    case 1:
           echo "pink";
    break;
    case 2: 
           echo "orange";
    break;
}
```

Should do what you want. Plenty of other ways to do it with arrays etc. Just the way I chose to show you :)

**EDIT:**
Array Method

```
$colors = array(1 => 'pink', 2 => 'orange');
$color = !empty($_POST['change_date'])?$_POST['change_date']:1;

echo "<body style='background-color:" . $colors[$color] . ";'></body>";
```

Both should work, pending any errors I made.

Comment: thats brilliant. can you give a little explanation of how this works?

Comment: Well it uses the `ternary` operator which acts as a short if. So if there is no post data, it defaults the variable so there isn't an undefined index error. The switch statement should be self explanatory. It takes in the variable and tests it against the case if it is equal to a case it enters it until a break then breaks out. Hopefully the array method is even more self explanatory. But note, this will not be persistent. If you want it to be you will need to look into `sessions` or `cookies`

Comment: Well just making sure, did you modify the code to be more correct, or just use it copy / paste straight off my answer. As you will need to add your code to it and add the 3rd case as well.

Answer (score 1):

your PHP code only works if the variable "change_date" comes from a query string via a POST method...

Do you need to set the color on the fly? or after sending a form?

Comment: I would do it via a javascript and then save the option in a cookie, that way the next pages would use the "new" colour.

Answer (score 1):

You're problem is in your use of `isset`.  This function simple returns a boolean value, not the value of the field. Try the below:

```
if(isset($_POST['change_date']))
{
    switch($_POST['change_date'])
    {
        case 1:
            echo "<body style='background-color:red;'></body>";
            break;
        case 2:
            echo "<body style='background-color:green;'></body>";
            break;
        case 3:
            echo "<body style='background-color:pink;'></body>";
            break;
        default:
            echo "<body style='background-color:white;'></body>";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "<body style='background-color:white;'></body>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way could be, if you dont wanna use switch statement ,

```
$color = isset($_POST['change_date']))?$_POST['change_date']:0;
if($color){

               if($color == 1) echo "<body style='background-color:red;'></body>";
               if($color == 2) echo "<body style='background-color:green;'></body>";
               if($color == 3) echo "<body style='background-color:pink;'></body>";
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a value map array, and as pointed out in one of the other answers it might be GET instead of POST, so I'm using $_REQUEST as example:

```
<?php
   $colors = array(
      1 => "red",
      2 => "green",
      3 => "pink",
   );

   if ($c = $colors[ $_REQUEST["change_date"] ])
   {
       echo "<body style='background-color: $c;'>body</body>";
   }
   else {
       echo "failed";
   }
```